# Prometheus: how to get label_value() in query

Tags: prometheus, grafana, metrics, promql

So I have 2 metrics, I need to get label values from first metric and then query over 2nd metric, where {param="label_values_from_1st_metric"}.
For ex:

### `metric_1{instance="abc"}` - returns 3 timeseries:

`metric_1{name="my-service", env="production", host="example-0.org"}`

`metric_1{name="my-service", env="production", host="example-1.org"}`

`metric_1{name="my-service", env="production", host="example-2.org"}`

#### Next I need to make query over 2nd metric using *host* values from 1st query.

`metric_2{domain="exmple-0,1,2.org"}`

So the question is, how I can pass label_values to 2nd query? As far as I understand, I can use label_values() only for variables in grafana panel, so I can't write one query that will do that for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, finally, I've got it. So As Pulak Kanti suggested, I used group_left. However it returned error: many-to-many mathcing is not allowed.
So what I've done:

1. Labels between *metric_1* and *metric_2* do not match, however it is pretty simple to fix it, we need to add label_replace() func
   `label_replace(metric_2,"host","$1","domain", "(.+)")`. This expression adds to metric_2 label *host* with values copied from label *domain*. From our point of view we've just renamed label *domain* to label *host*. And this is great news, because now metric_1 and metric_2 have one common label - *host*.
   So the query from this step would look something like this:

   `label_replace(metric_2,"host","$1","domain", "(.+)") + on (host) group_left(domain)  metric_1{instance="abc"}`
2. Now our query at least doesn't retrun any error, however, it returns unexpected result-this is because it multiplies values from metric_2 with values from metric_1. Because we need only values from metric_2, we can just null metric_1, so it ends up being:
   `label_replace(metric_2,"host","$1","domain", "(.+)") + on (host) group_left(domain)  0*metric_1{instance="abc"}`

I do understand that this query isn't effective, however it worked for me. I would be very grateful if someone would help and make this query more efficient.
BTW: here it is not important what is inside group_left() brackets, because it influences only what label we displays, for me it is not important, so
`label_replace(metric_2,"host","$1","domain", "(.+)") + on (host) group_left()  0*metric_1{instance="abc"}` also works.

Answer (score 5):

You can try in the following way:

```
metric_2 * on(instance) group_left(host) metric_1{instance="abc"}
```

- **on(instance) =>**  this is how to JOIN on label instance.
- **group_left(host) metric_1{instance="abc"} =>**   means, keep the label host from metric_1 in the result.

Comment: Thanks. And do you know, how I can fix "found duplicate series for the match group", "many-to-many matching not allowed: matching labels must be unique on one side". If I understand correctly, the problem is that metric_1{instance="abc"} returns 3 timeseries, not one?

Comment: Yes, I think. It doesn't work for many to many scenario.

Comment: Jesus, why it is so complicated. Are there any workarounds? Maybe there is any hack how I can make query over metric_2 with labels, retrieved from another query?

Answer (score 0):

The following query may work faster if it is executed by optimized Prometheus-compatible query engine such as [VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/):

```
metric_2 and on(domain) label_copy(metric_1{instance="abc"}, "host", "domain")
```

VictoriaMetrics starts from the right part of the `a and b` query, e.g. it executes `label_copy(metric_1{instance="abc"}, "host", "domain")`. Then it finds unique `domain` label values for the returned time series and passes an additional label filter on the `domain` label to the left part of the `a and b` query. Then it executes the left part of the query - `metric_2{domain=~"domain1|...|domainN"}` - and returns the matching time series.

Without this optimization all the time series with `metric_2` name are selected before being dropped during the execution of `a and b` query according to [these matching rules](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#logical-set-binary-operators).